# Google Cloud Tasks enforcing rate limit on forwarding to Cloud Functions?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-tasks

Cloud Tasks is saying:

> App Engine is enforcing a processing rate lower than the maximum rate for this queue either because your application is returning HTTP 503 codes or because currently there is no instance available to execute a request.

However, I am forwarding the tasks to a cloud function using an HTTP POST request, similar to the one outlined in [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@rogiervandenberg/google-cloud-task-queues-on-gcp-with-google-cloud-functions-22eb80fe34ba). I don't see any 503s in my logs for the cloud function that it forwards to.

My `queue.yaml` is:

```
queue:
- name: task-queue-1
  rate: 3/s
  bucket_size: 500
  max_concurrent_requests: 100
  retry_parameters:
    task_retry_limit: 1
    min_backoff_seconds: 120
    task_age_limit: 7d
```

[image]

Comment: What the problem? The enforce rate is too low, right? If so, how many task do you have stacked in your queue?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I had about 64k tasks in the queue.

Comment: Do you have logs of the called service? Everything is OK?

Comment: Yes. I don't see any 503s in my logs for the cloud function that it forwards to. It is successfully processing the tasks, just really slowly. I am now down to 28k tasks at the moment from 64k yesterday. Still at a reduced rate.

Comment: Any other code except 200 OK ? Some very long request?

Comment: Could you please tell us more about your actual workflow? What is the role of Cloud Task on it? Do you expect to provide a result to your users each time Cloud Tasks is used?

Comment: Cloud Task sends a POST request to the HTTP endpoint of our cloud function. The cloud function takes between 30-60 seconds, with a timeout of 120 seconds. Does Cloud Tasks maintain that HTTP connection, and maybe is timing out? Is that why it's slowing the queue down?

Comment: Cloud Tasks [is not designed](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/dual-overview?hl=en) to guarantee timing of tasks delivery however, we don't have enough evidence or tools right now to know if this implementation is the one causing the 503 Error messages.

Comment: I would suggest to contact [GCP support](https://console.cloud.google.com/support/) directly to perform a deeper inspection. You can also create a [Public Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to come from *any* exception, even though only 503 is listed. If the cloud function responds with any error the task queue slows down the rate, and you have no control over that.

My solution was to swallow any errors to prevent that propagating up to Google's automatic check.